# Which vim version do I have?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I remember having to select one of multiple versions of vim last time I installed it on Ubuntu.

Now I'm ssh-in other machine and I would like to know which version is there. How to check that?

What I tried:

```
$ man vim
$ apt -a list vim
$ apt-cache policy vim
```

None of these refers to `tiny/full/basic` (I think these are the names, not sure).

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2466/how-do-i-know-the-patch-version-of-my-vim

Answer (score 7):

Just type this at terminal :

```
vim --version
```

Or Open Vi editor and type :

```
:ve
```

On my terminal, It shows something like this :

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Nov 24 2016 16:44:48)
Included patches: 1-1689
Extra patches: 8.0.0056
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +farsi           +mouse_netterm   +tag_binary
+arabic          +file_in_path
```

Use Vim's online help for more details by typing (in editor) :

```
:help version
```

Feel free to add-in more details.